How to apply OR function with a member of a list
I'm using the following function to filter a column in an array
=OR(Q14="test1"; Q14="test2")

I would like to do the following formula:

=OR(Q14 is equal to a member of a list that is stored in another cell as a string)

For example the A1 cell is filled with {"test1","test2","test3","test4",..,"testn"}
and I would like to use

=OR(Q14=an element of the above list)

I need it to implement the formula in the sheet not using a  script to put the result in a sheet.


Split the Values for Checking and then Compare the Q14 to the Values
You may try this:
=IF(COUNTIF(BYCOL(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"{",""),"}",""),CHAR(34)&","&CHAR(34)),lambda(x,Q14=x)),TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)

This formula checks the value of Q14 if it exists in the list in A1, formatted like {"test1","test2","test3","test4",..,"testn"}. SUBSTITUTE removes the braces. Then, the SPLIT Function splits the string into an array. Afterwards, if a match is found, the formula returns TRUE; otherwise, it returns FALSE.
Sample Output:

Reference:
Google Sheets function list

Another way - you can try REGEXMATCH:
=REGEXMATCH(A1,""""&B1&"""")


